# Scheduling specific function for discord bot at certain time

Tags: python, discord

So I want to make a discord bot that does some function at certain time (ex: 22:30), and while it is not 22:30 I want to make bot work as usual, receiving messages, sending, and etc.

```
import someFile
import discord
import responses
from discord.ext import commands

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = ''
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    client = discord.Client(command_prefix="-", intents = intents)
    if time == specificTime:
        someFile.someFunction() #run this file at specific time
    else: #run bot as usual
        @client.event
        async def on_ready():
            print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.author == client.user:
                return
            username = str(message.author)
            user_message = str(message.content)
            channel = str(message.channel)
            print(f'{username} said: {user_message} ({channel})')
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Is there any way to do it? I can't really find any solutions on google...

Comment: For Pycord: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop

For Discord.py:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import someFile
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import asyncio

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = ''
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    client = discord.Client(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    async def job():
        #Function...

    # Schedule the job to run at 22:30
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', hour=22, minute=30)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)
        print(f'{username} said: {user_message} ({channel})')
        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)

    client.run(TOKEN)

    try:
        scheduler.start()
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()
```